# How can an improper integral approach a value?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I have $\int_1^\infty\frac {1}{x^2}  dx$, which converges to 1. If the region under the curve from 1 to infinity on the function $f(x) = \frac {1}{x^2}$ has infinite area when graphed (even though the function approaches zero as x goes to infinity), how can the integral approach a singular value?

Comment: Do you mean that the area is infinite? With what interpretation of area?

Comment: It has not infinite area: it has a finite area.

Comment: Alright, I was under the impression that since the integral's bound goes to infinity there must be an infinite area under the curve.

Comment: No the value as x^2 increases 1/x^2 becomes so less that y becomes approximately 0 thus area is $1$

Answer (score 0):

The definition of the improper integral is as follows:

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)dx =\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{n} f(x)dx$$

So just as the limit of some function can have a finite value, the improper integral can also have a finite value.